# For which constants does the following converge to a delta function?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

let $g_n(x,y)=\frac{c_n}{1+n^2(x^2+y^2)}$

for which constants, $c_n$ , does the function converge to a delta function as n becomes arbitrarily large?

My intitial thought, corroborated by plots in maple, is that if $c_n$ is monotonically increasing in n, then the function will converge.

Any other ideas?  How does my idea sound?  Hints are appreciated.

Comment: Depending on your definition of a delta function this may not be possible, since the integral of your function over $\mathbb{R}^2$ doesn't converge for any $n$, no matter what $c_n$ is. As far as I know, the delta function must verify $\int_\mathbb{R} \delta(x)\ dx = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need it to grow to infinity at one point, and go to zero at all others. If you look at the denominator, then for $(x,y)\not=(0,0)$ you have something like $$\frac{c_n}{1+\alpha n^2},\alpha>0$$ which is going to either grow to infinity, converge to some finite positive values or go to zero depending on how $\{c_n\}$ behaves, but "uniformly" for every $\alpha>0$ (i.e. if it converges to infinity for one $\alpha>0$, it will for another).

So, to make it $\delta$-function you want the expression above to go to zero for all $\alpha>0$, and grow to $+\infty$ for $\alpha=0$. This leads to conclusion that $\frac{c_n}{n^2}\rightarrow0$, while $c_n\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: Great, thanks !